# jQuery check if "undefined" after each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Here's what's supposed to be happening. Each time the user clicks a button, the text of a div changes. I've got this working perfectly (thanks to a previous question here). Each click generates a cookie with some random text that then appears in the divs. There are 5 divs (one for each cookie) that get filled up and then the first is overwritten (on the 6th click). Like I said, this is working perfect.

However, when someone clicks for the first time, the first div has the text correctly appear, but "undefined" appears in the other 4 divs (because the other cookies aren't defined yet). I suppose this is expected based on the code. However, I'd like it so that if the content of those divs is "undefined" the div remains hidden.

Here's the code for the divs:

```
<div id="textDiv" class="div"></div>
<div id="textDiv1" class="div1"></div>
<div id="textDiv2" class="div2"></div>
<div id="textDiv3" class="div3"></div>
<div id="textDiv4" class="div4"></div>
```

Here's the code to fill in each div (but repeated 5 times to cover all 5 cookies and 5 divs...left out all of it save space:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").click(function () {
var div = document.getElementById("textDiv");
div.textContent = $.cookie('cookie_1');
var text = div.textContent;
})
}); 
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").click(function () {
var div = document.getElementById("textDiv1");
div.textContent = $.cookie('cookie_2');
var text = div.textContent;
})
}); 
</script>

ETC...
```

Like I said, this works fine, but the divs display "undefined" before the cookies are all set. I tried this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").click(function () {
var $cook1 = $.cookie('cookie_1');
var $cook2 = $.cookie('cookie_2');
var $cook3 = $.cookie('cookie_3');
var $cook4 = $.cookie('cookie_4');
var $cook0 = $.cookie('cookie_0');
})
}); 
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").click(function () {
if(typeof cook2 == 'undefined'){
    $('textDiv1').hide();
    }
else {
     var div = document.getElementById("textDiv1");
div.textContent = $.cookie('cookie_2');
var text = div.textContent; 
}
})
}); 
</script>

ETC...
```

This does hide the div when the cookie (and therefore text in the div) is undefined. The only problem is that once the cookie is defined (after another click on the form), it doesn't unhide. It doesn't seem to "recheck" whether or not it is defined. This is odd to me because it seems like it checks the cookie on each click because the text in the divs change as the cookies change.

Any idea how to do this?

(And yes, I'm assuming that I've made my code far too complicated and there are lots of ways to simplify, but I'm new at this, so I'll take all your suggestions.)

(Note: I left out the code for generating cookies, which works fine and I don't think applies to the answer.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler, and should work:

```
div.textContent = $.cookie('cookie_1') || "";
```

Also, I see a lot of repetition in your code, you can simplify it like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    function fillDiv(divId, cookieId) {
        var div = document.getElementById(divId);
        div.textContent = $.cookie(cookieId) || "";
    }

    $("form").click(function () {
        fillDiv("textDiv", "cookie_1");
        fillDiv("textDiv1", "cookie_2");
        // etc.
    })
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Good grief. That was amazingly simple compared to what I had. And it actually worked! Thanks for the help. I still have A LOT to learn.